# Execute SQL Server stored procedure with input parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Could you suggest please how to execute from Sql Server a stored procedure that receives an input parameter? I tried this but it failed:

```
EXEC GetFilmsInCategory('SF');
```

The stored procedure is correctly defined, by the way. I executed it from the visual interface and it worked, with this code generated automatically:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[GetFilmsInCategory] @CatNume = N'SF'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I find this automatically generated code too... lengthy as I was expecting something similar to what I initially tried:

```
EXEC GetFilmsInCategory('SF');
```

Can you fix this or offer an alternative? Thank you!

Anna

Comment: `GO` is not an actual SQL command. It's actually just a batch delimiter for use in SSMS. When it is used it needs to be on a separate line by itself.

Comment: Indeed, John, thanks for the heads up. I was neglectful about that when typing the question.

Comment: How can I do that, John? By marking the answers? I just marked yours.

Comment: Thanks, but the rate percentage is actually calculated from checking Accepted next to @Jmyster's answer below:)

Comment: There are up votes, and checking the answer. You upvoted Johns comment which you do when they help you out, now click on the Check mark by any "Answer" you find to solve you problem. Answers will be in there own sections and not a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TRY:

```
EXEC GetFilmsInCategory 'SF'
```

Comment: Checking a comment as great is equivalent to checking it as an answer? Thanks for the advice and tip, Jmyster.

Comment: There you go. Welcome to SO =).

Comment: @Manishearth No need to. It's a very simple process. All that was needed was a single line of code. She got the point and it worked for her. Please don't comment if you have nothing useful. -1

Comment: The goal of SO is not to become a quick-fix forum where specific  answers to all issues are  provided. The answers should help _others_ learn as well. If you feel that this answer is all that the question deserves, then _don't answer_. "The post is bad" does not justify bad answers. (By "bad" I mean unsuitable for the SE network). If the question can be answered with a one-liner and nothing mire, downvote, comment, closevote, but don't answer.

Comment: You interpretation of SO goal is different than mine. Sometimes someone just needs a bit of help. This user posted what they tried. They gave effort to what they where doing. I felt that was worthy enough to help them. Neither my answer or their post are out of line. I'm sure they learned and will not repeat their problem. Please put down your SO badge and look at yourself and the SO "goals" about not going off topic. This is not a question but a statement that does not need a response.

Answer (score 3):

You can also address the parameters by name:

```
EXEC GetFilmsInCategory @CatNume = 'SF'
```