# Why my sql query is bad formatted from ExecuteNonQuery method?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with these parameters :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@myParam1 nvarchar(50),
@myParam2 date,
@myParam3 date,
@myParam4 time,
@myParam5 time,
@myParam6 int = 1,
@myParam7 nvarchar(50),
@myParam8 int,
@myParam9 nvarchar(50),
@myParam10 nvarchar(500),
@myParam11 nvarchar(100) = NULL,
@myParam12 nvarchar(1000) = NULL,
@myParam13 nvarchar(100) = NULL,
@myParam14 nvarchar(1000) = NULL,
@myParam15 date = NULL,
@myParam16 bit = NULL,
@myParam17 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@myParam18 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@myParam19 nvarchar(500) = NULL,
@myParam20 bit = NULL,
@myParam21 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@myParam22 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@myParam23 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@myParam24 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@myParam25 nvarchar(500) = NULL,
@myParam26 int = NULL,
@myParam27 int = NULL
```

AS
...

And this is How I call it using C# :

```
string sqlQuery = "[dbo].[myStoredProc] @myParam1, @myParam2, @myParam3,    @myParam4, @myParam5, @myParam6, @myParam7, @myParam8, @myParam9, @myParam10, @myParam11, @myParam12, @myParam13, @myParam14";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam1", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "Nouri, Florian" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam2", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date, Value = DateTime.Today });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam3", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date, Value = DateTime.Today });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam4", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Time, Value = "9:30" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam5", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Time, Value = "10:30" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam6", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "this is param6" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam7", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = 4 });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam8", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "param8" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam9", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "param9" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam10", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "Nouri, Florian" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam11", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam12", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam13", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = "" });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@myParam14", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, Value = 1 });

conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

and when I execute the code, I get a bad formatted string (in the SQL Profiler) :

```
exec sp_executesql N'[dbo].[myStoredProc] @myParam1, @myParam2, @myParam3, @myParam4, @myParam5, @myParam6, @myParam7, @myParam8, @myParam9, 
@myParam10, @myParam11, @myParam12, @myParam13, @myParam14',N'@myParam1 nvarchar(14),@myParam2 date,@myParam3 date,@myParam4 time(7),@myParam5 time(7),@myParam6 nvarchar(22),@myParam7 int,@myParam8 nvarchar(8),@myParam9 nvarchar(8),@myParam10 nvarchar(14),@myParam11 nvarchar(4000),@myParam12 nvarchar(4000),@myParam13 nvarchar(4000),@myParam14 int',@myParam1=N'Nouri, Florian',@myParam2='2016-10-03',@myParam3='2016-10-03',@myParam4='09:30:00',@myParam5='10:30:00',@myParam6=N'this is param6',@myParam7=4,@myParam8=N'param8',@myParam9=N'param9',@myParam10=N'Nouri, Florian',@myParam11=N'',@myParam12=N'',@myParam13=N'',@myParam14=1
```

I don't know why types and length (nvarchar, time...) is in the string. Any idea ? I try to use `AddWithParameter` method but I get the same string.

Comment: You either need to specify 'EXEC [dbo].[myStoredProc]` or set the `SqlCommand` type to Procedure !

Comment: Tag the dbms used. That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.

Comment: You say it's "bad formatted" - but is it actually causing you a *problem*? Do you get an error message (if so, what?). Is your objection merely to the length of the string parameters (if so, you should be able to specify the lengths you want in your C# code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10806397/60188). What you're missing is one more `EXEC`:

```
string sqlQuery = "exec [dbo].[myStoredProc] ..."
```

Which will produce the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec [dbo].[myStoredProc] ...'
```

Alternatively, you can use `CommandType.StoredProcedure` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9267701/60188).

Comment: it's effectively that ! I leave the string sqlQuery = "[dbo].[myStoredProc]"; but specified CommandType.StoredProcedure

Comment: I've now the same problem with a Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand and impossible to specify the query as a stored procedure :-/

Comment: I think that `ExecuteSqlCommand()` expects the `exec [dbo].[MyStoredProc]` syntax